# Cannot exclude packages from IntelliJ test coverage report

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, junit, code-coverage

I have explicitly set the packages I want included in the code coverage report and also set the ones I want to be ignored. Also, to get the most accurate results, I have set it to Tracing instead of Sampling:

[image]

Then I run "Analyze -> Generate coverage report". In a few moments, the report gets opened in the browser. However, I see the excluded packages in the report.

What am I doing wrong? How do I force the undesired packages to be excluded?

IDE information: Android Studio 3.5.2

The project structure is organized as follows:

[image]

I would like to exclude everything under opencv.

This is a legacy project and I don't exactly know, how OpenCV was added. Here's what I found when looking for references:

- settings.gradle has `include ':app', ':opencv'`
- build.gradle has the following:

```
dependencies {
    ..
    implementation project(':opencv')
```

OpenCV is added as a separate Android project with its own AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Hi! Is the issue reproduced for you with simple sample project? Or only with the particular one? If yes, please share the sample. Thank you

Comment: @OlgaKlisho  It is a large legacy project. I now added a screenshot with the project structure.Maybe there's something specific to file locations, why opencv files get included even if I explicitly excluded them?

Comment: Do I get it right that you have opencv sources added as library? How was it added? Please clarify

Comment: @OlgaKlisho  I updated the question with more details about what I found when inspecting the OpenCV dependency.

Comment: If possible can you please file an issue at the YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) attaching a little sample project to reproduce the behaviour. Thank you

Comment: @OlgaKlisho  It seems, the issue was fixed in later versions. I updated to Android Studio 4.0.1 and now ignored packages are not present in the coverage report, as expected.